# Difference between Long.toBinaryString() and Long.toString(num, 2)?

Tags: java

Both of these functions convert a Long to a binary String, but is one more optimized than the other? I looked at the source code for the Long class and these two static methods have different implementations.

Comment: I would be shocked if `toBinaryString` wasn't optimized for the task.

Comment: toString uses remainder and division ops to build the digits but toBinaryString uses right shifts. But I'm not sure if the compiler optimizes division by and and remainder of 2 using shifts. So I can't really tell if there's going to be any major difference. If the compiler optimization is in place then I expect them to be quite similar. Just my thoughts, not sure if that's true or not.

Comment: From a quick benchmark (still not with JMH/JIT analysis, but adhering some Microbenchmarking practices), it seems that the "core" loop of the conversion (that writes the digits into a `char` buffer) may only be ~25% slower for the generic `toString` method. **But** a considerable additional overhead may stem from the fact that in the `toString` method, the relevant part of the `char` array has to be *copied* when creating the string. In `toBinaryString`, the number of required characters is computed *directly*, and the resulting `char` array is passed to the string *without* copying it.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is how negative numbers are displayed.

```
var s = System.out;
Long oL = 0L;
long num = -1;

s.println(oL.toString(num, 2) );     //binary result
s.println(oL.toBinaryString(num) );

s.println("0x"+oL.toHexString(num).toUpperCase() );
```

Output:

```
-1
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

**toString()** uses mathematical notation.

**toBinaryString(**) respects the way how negative numbers are actually implemented in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy to get, just do a test:

```
class Test {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    long millisStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        String s = Long.toBinaryString(i / 10000);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millisStart);

    millisStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        String st = Long.toString(i / 10000, 2);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - millisStart);
  }
}
```

On the system I tested this on (Raspberry Pi), this results in 655 against 3279.

So, I would guess that Long.toString(num, 2); is slower. Which is no wonder, as it has to be flexible.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, but) although a *proper* benchmark would likely come to a similar conclusion, the benchmark in the given form is **NOT** reliable in any way.

Comment: Wasn't meant to be a proper benchmark. However, when it comes to magnitudes in differences, combined with specialization for certain functions, it still gives a clear answer to "is one more optimized than the other?".

Comment: Thanks for the test Florian. I'm more looking to see if someone can peek at the source code and explain WHY toBinaryString is more optimized, assuming it is. (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: @user2603017 No worries, helps to clarify the intention of the question. As Armin J hinted, optimizers can have quite an influence here. Jit compilers tend to behave differently depending on the platform as well.